# How to parse more than 2 level ini file with Boost

Tags: c++, parsing, boot, ini

I want to have an ini file with more than just 2 levels ... something like this

```
[Section1]
Value1 = 10
Value2 = a_text_string

[Section2]
[SubSection1]
Value1=1
Value2=2

[Section2]
[SubSection2]
Value1=a
Value2=b
```

**Qn 1. How to create such ini file?**

After that I want to load these values and print them in my application with Boost

****Qn2. Will this work?*** If not how can I do that?*

```
boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
boost::property_tree::ini_parser::read_ini("config.ini", pt);
std::cout << pt.get<std::string>("Section1.Value1") << std::endl;
std::cout << pt.get<std::string>("Section2.Subsection1.Value2") << std::endl;
```

Comment: What distinguishes a subsection from a new section? Are you able to change the format specification? If so, you can change it, so that the section names can start with a nesting level specifier: `[1:Subsection1]` Though if you can change the specification, why not go for something like XML, right?

Comment: @enobayram And why would you choose something as verbose as XML over JSON? ;)

Comment: @cdhowie I wouldn't choose XML over JSON, I'd choose it over my ugly suggestion :) It was just meant to be an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

INI files do not support structure like this.  If you want to have different structural levels in an INI file, you have to specify the full path in each section:

```
[Section1]
Value1 = 10
Value2 = a_text_string

[Section2.SubSection1]
Value1=1
Value2=2

[Section2.SubSection2]
Value1=a
Value2=b
```

The actual "Section2." prefix means nothing specific in the INI grammar, it's just a way for you to create this kind of structure in a language that doesn't support it via nesting.